# Android emulator failed to start after 360 seconds

Tags: android, jenkins

I have `Jenkins` 1.568 installed on a `Macbook Air` running `Ubuntu 14.04`. I have the android emulator plugin installed, and the configuration I have set up runs the emulator in `-no-window` mode before starting each build.

About half of the builds are fine, but the other half, I get the following on the console:

```
[android] Starting Android emulator
$ /usr/local/src/android/android-sdk-linux/tools/emulator -no-boot-anim -ports 5782,5783 -avd Caesar -no-snapshot-load -no-snapshot-save -no-window -no-audio -no-skin -no-window
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5784 *
* daemon started successfully *
Failed to Initialize backend EGL display
$ /usr/local/src/android/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb connect emulator-5782
[android] Waiting for emulator to finish booting...
$ /usr/local/src/android/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb -s emulator-5782 shell getprop dev.bootcomplete
error: device offline
$ /usr/local/src/android/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb connect emulator-5782
$ /usr/local/src/android/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb -s emulator-5782 shell getprop dev.bootcomplete
error: device offline
$ /usr/local/src/android/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb connect emulator-5782
$ /usr/local/src/android/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb -s emulator-5782 shell getprop dev.bootcomplete
error: device offline
$ /usr/local/src/android/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb disconnect emulator-5782
$ /usr/local/src/android/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb connect emulator-5782
$ /usr/local/src/android/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb -s emulator-5782 shell getprop dev.bootcomplete
error: device offline
$ /usr/local/src/android/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb connect emulator-5782
$ /usr/local/src/android/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb -s emulator-5782 shell getprop dev.bootcomplete
error: device offline
$ /usr/local/src/android/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb connect emulator-5782
$ /usr/local/src/android/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb -s emulator-5782 shell getprop dev.bootcomplete
error: device offline
$ /usr/local/src/android/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb disconnect emulator-5782
$ /usr/local/src/android/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb connect emulator-5782
$ /usr/local/src/android/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb -s emulator-5782 shell getprop dev.bootcomplete
error: device offline
$ /usr/local/src/android/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb connect emulator-5782
$ /usr/local/src/android/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb -s emulator-5782 shell getprop dev.bootcomplete
error: device offline
$ /usr/local/src/android/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb connect emulator-5782
$ /usr/local/src/android/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb -s emulator-5782 shell getprop dev.bootcomplete
error: device offline
$ /usr/local/src/android/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb disconnect emulator-5782
$ /usr/local/src/android/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb connect emulator-5782
$ /usr/local/src/android/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb -s emulator-5782 shell getprop dev.bootcomplete
error: device offline
$ /usr/local/src/android/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb connect emulator-5782
$ /usr/local/src/android/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb -s emulator-5782 shell getprop dev.bootcomplete
error: device offline
$ /usr/local/src/android/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb connect emulator-5782
$ /usr/local/src/android/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb -s emulator-5782 shell getprop dev.bootcomplete
error: device offline
$ /usr/local/src/android/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb disconnect emulator-5782
$ /usr/local/src/android/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb connect emulator-5782
$ /usr/local/src/android/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb -s emulator-5782 shell getprop dev.bootcomplete
error: device offline
$ /usr/local/src/android/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb connect emulator-5782
$ /usr/local/src/android/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb -s emulator-5782 shell getprop dev.bootcomplete
error: device offline
$ /usr/local/src/android/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb connect emulator-5782
$ /usr/local/src/android/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb -s emulator-5782 shell getprop dev.bootcomplete
error: device offline
$ /usr/local/src/android/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb disconnect emulator-5782
$ /usr/local/src/android/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb connect emulator-5782
$ /usr/local/src/android/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb -s emulator-5782 shell getprop dev.bootcomplete
error: device offline
$ /usr/local/src/android/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb connect emulator-5782
$ /usr/local/src/android/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb -s emulator-5782 shell getprop dev.bootcomplete
error: device offline
$ /usr/local/src/android/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb connect emulator-5782
$ /usr/local/src/android/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb -s emulator-5782 shell getprop dev.bootcomplete
error: device offline
$ /usr/local/src/android/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb disconnect emulator-5782
$ /usr/local/src/android/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb connect emulator-5782
$ /usr/local/src/android/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb -s emulator-5782 shell getprop dev.bootcomplete
error: device offline
$ /usr/local/src/android/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb connect emulator-5782
$ /usr/local/src/android/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb -s emulator-5782 shell getprop dev.bootcomplete
error: device offline
$ /usr/local/src/android/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb connect emulator-5782
$ /usr/local/src/android/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb -s emulator-5782 shell getprop dev.bootcomplete
error: device offline
$ /usr/local/src/android/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb disconnect emulator-5782
$ /usr/local/src/android/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb connect emulator-5782
$ /usr/local/src/android/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb -s emulator-5782 shell getprop dev.bootcomplete
error: device offline
$ /usr/local/src/android/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb connect emulator-5782
$ /usr/local/src/android/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb -s emulator-5782 shell getprop dev.bootcomplete
error: device offline
$ /usr/local/src/android/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb connect emulator-5782
$ /usr/local/src/android/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb -s emulator-5782 shell getprop dev.bootcomplete
error: device offline
$ /usr/local/src/android/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb disconnect emulator-5782
$ /usr/local/src/android/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb connect emulator-5782
$ /usr/local/src/android/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb -s emulator-5782 shell getprop dev.bootcomplete
error: device offline
$ /usr/local/src/android/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb connect emulator-5782
$ /usr/local/src/android/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb -s emulator-5782 shell getprop dev.bootcomplete
error: device offline
$ /usr/local/src/android/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb connect emulator-5782
$ /usr/local/src/android/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb -s emulator-5782 shell getprop dev.bootcomplete
error: device offline
$ /usr/local/src/android/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb disconnect emulator-5782
$ /usr/local/src/android/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb connect emulator-5782
$ /usr/local/src/android/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb -s emulator-5782 shell getprop dev.bootcomplete
error: device offline
$ /usr/local/src/android/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb connect emulator-5782
$ /usr/local/src/android/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb -s emulator-5782 shell getprop dev.bootcomplete
error: device offline
$ /usr/local/src/android/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb connect emulator-5782
$ /usr/local/src/android/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb -s emulator-5782 shell getprop dev.bootcomplete
error: device offline
$ /usr/local/src/android/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb disconnect emulator-5782
$ /usr/local/src/android/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb connect emulator-5782
$ /usr/local/src/android/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb -s emulator-5782 shell getprop dev.bootcomplete
error: device offline
$ /usr/local/src/android/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb connect emulator-5782
$ /usr/local/src/android/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb -s emulator-5782 shell getprop dev.bootcomplete
error: device offline
$ /usr/local/src/android/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb connect emulator-5782
$ /usr/local/src/android/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb -s emulator-5782 shell getprop dev.bootcomplete
error: device offline
$ /usr/local/src/android/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb disconnect emulator-5782
$ /usr/local/src/android/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb connect emulator-5782
$ /usr/local/src/android/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb -s emulator-5782 shell getprop dev.bootcomplete
error: device offline
$ /usr/local/src/android/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb connect emulator-5782
$ /usr/local/src/android/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb -s emulator-5782 shell getprop dev.bootcomplete
error: device offline
$ /usr/local/src/android/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb connect emulator-5782
$ /usr/local/src/android/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb -s emulator-5782 shell getprop dev.bootcomplete
error: device offline
$ /usr/local/src/android/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb disconnect emulator-5782
$ /usr/local/src/android/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb connect emulator-5782
$ /usr/local/src/android/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb -s emulator-5782 shell getprop dev.bootcomplete
error: device offline
$ /usr/local/src/android/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb connect emulator-5782
[android] Timed-out after waiting 360 seconds for emulator
$ /usr/local/src/android/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb disconnect emulator-5782
[android] Stopping Android emulator
```

Clearly, the emulator is failing about 50% of the time. I'm not sure why, though, or how to fix it. Any suggestions would be welcome as to how I can get this running and not have to restart failed builds using naginator.

Comment: Did you solve the problem? I'm facing exactly the same

Comment: No, sorry Pedro. I haven't solved this yet. I'm still waiting for an answer. In the meantime, I've mitigated it by having the builds run again (up to a max of 5 tries) if they fail. Not an optimal solution, but better than just having it fail and stay failed.

Comment: Thanks, I'm been looking for a solution but nothing  found, so I have a build with java test for modular things that doesn't depend on emulator and another job to to the testing only, where I'm launching it the times is needed. so now I have my release builds downloaded from jenkins, the only bad thing is all my emulator dependent testing cases that have to be launched in a different job.If I find a solution I'll post it!

Comment: Is this a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23699433/android-emulator-jenkins-plugin-not-working ? I am also facing this, and came across this other one

Comment: @KarthikT It might be. Let me see if the solution on that question works for me.

Comment: @jwir3 I ended up just not using the emulator, just going a compile and artifact.. I dont have tests anyway in this proj so it was enuf for me

Comment: This bug bite us again. https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-11952?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:all-tabpanel . Please vote and comment there

Comment: What API level are you targeting? What sysimg are you using? What version of the build tools? I've seen this with the older versions of the tools.

Comment: @LyndseyFerguson I'm targeting android 19.1.0, with the latest version of the build tools. The sysimage I am using is an emulator version that is designed to emulate a nexus 5 (so android 4.4.4).

Comment: Have you installed the HAXM accelerator to speed it up? Also, have you increased the amount of VM and RAM via the Jenkins "custom hardware property"? I have done so on my own experimentation and seen drastic slow downs (however it did eventually connect to the emulator after only 117 secs).

Comment: Hmm, no I haven't installed the HAXM accelerator. I was running this on a macbook air with Ubuntu 14.04 installed on it, and I found that it was pretty finicky about starting the emulator (I only got one specific configuration to work, and it didn't include the HAXM accelerator).

Comment: If anyone is still active in this thread with the problem, is it failing about 50% of the time in a random order?  Or is there a pattern to the failed runs, as in if it ran last time it will fail this time and vice versa.. ?

Comment: -verbose may give more debug info

Answer (score 1):

Try to update Java. I had android emulator problems in the past and a Java update fixed them.

Answer (score 1):

**Timeout problems.**

DdmPreferences.setTimeOut is the global adb read/write packet timeout setting.
In 'at com.android.ddmlib.SyncService.doPushFile(SyncService.java:671)', DdmPreferences.getTimeOut() is called and used to set timeout.

In build.gradle:

```
android{
...
   adbOptions {
        timeOutInMs 10 * 60 * 1000 // 10 minutes
    }
}
```

For Eclipse (Preferences -> Android -> DDMS).

Also, this is an environment variable that you set outside of build.gradle. On Ubuntu for instance:

```
$ export ADB_INSTALL_TIMEOUT=5
$ ./gradlew installDebug
```

Between runs:

sudo adb kill-server

and

sudo adb start-server

Answer (score 0):

**Here is a checklist to help:**

1) You need the --all flag for both android list and android update sdk, otherwise some packages will not be installed: ex for SDK 24

1a)$ANDROID_HOME/tools/android list sdk --all

1b)

```
(for i in {1..100}; do echo y; sleep 1; done) |
$ANDROID_HOME/tools/android update sdk --no-ui --all --filter 
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,20,21,22,23,24,25,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,79,80,81,82,82,84,85,101,102,103,112,113,117,118,119,120,121,122,123,124
```

if you get the dreaded /home/jenkins/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb -s emulator-XXXX shell getprop dev.bootcomplete error: device offline error, you are likely missing a package in step 1b

2)Ignore the dreaded Failed to Initialize backend EGL display error, it is a red herring

3)Be sure to use the Advanced Emulator options:

```
Emulator Options: -no-audio -gpu off
Emulator executable: emulator64-arm
Startup delay: 10  -- this *may* help
```

4)a pre-build script `${ANDROID_HOME}/platform-tools/adb kill-server` can't hurt
check out Jenkins site https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-27456
https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-11952
you can also check this one https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=209955 and http://www.yzjingying.net/4855150152.htm
Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

I just found solution [Android Emulator Plugin Failed to Initialize backend EGL display](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22335312/2949612)

Compare your job configuration with https://partnerdemo.ci.cloudbees.com/job/Android-dev/job/stockfish-android-cloud/, paying particular attention to the following settings:

```
Inject env var: LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/android/android-sdk-linux/tool/lib
Target ABI: armeabi-v7a
Advanced -> Emulator Options: -no-audio -gpu off
Advanced -> Emulator Executable: emulator64-arm
```

I hope its helps you.

Comment: This answer is already on diffferent question. The configuration link doesn't work. I don't see anything wrong on my configuration. Its invoking the emulator, but unable to start the emulatore